# What does this mean in the django documentation about class-based views?

Tags: python, django, view

A rookie here. As I am reading the django documentation, I came up with a note that I cannot fully understand.

It says:
Note
While your class is instantiated for each request dispatched to it, class attributes set through the as_view() entry point are configured only once at the time your URLs are imported.
Here is the link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/

So which one is better? What advantage does each have? I've tried both and cannot experience any difference(Pretty sure that's because I've not considered enough)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing any values into the as_view() method that are likely to change after the server starts, for example some function call or database query whose return value could change after some users use the website, it will be evaluated only once, while the urls are loaded.

Let's say you are passing in the current time like:

```
path('about/', GreetingView.as_view(greeting=timezone.now())),
```

That note simply says that the value of the attribute 'greeting' for GreetingView will stay the same for all requests even if the server runs for a month, since timezone.now() is called only once.

Such arguments are good for reusing a View class with minimal changes. It depends completely on your use case.
For example:

```
path('add-car/', AddView.as_view(form=AddCarForm)),
path('add-bus/', AddView.as_view(form=AddBusForm)),
```